# How can I, if you press a widget for a long time, create a "Settings" button between delete and info?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-widget

How can I, if you press a widget for a long time, create a "Settings" button between delete and info? You can find this on Samsung calendars, for example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I, if you press a widget for a long time, create a "Settings" button between delete and info?

That is not possible in general. The behavior of a long-click on an app widget is up to the developers who implemented the home screen, not you or I. Certain home screen implementations may have an API or convention that enables this, but it will not work across all home screen implementations.

> You can find this on Samsung calendars, for example.

Not necessarily. Make sure that you are testing with a launcher/home screen implementation that is not Samsung's.

The developer of a home screen is welcome to create "widgets" that:

- Are not really app widgets, but rather are features of the home screen that present like app widgets; or
- Have a private protocol with other apps that enable certain options that are not available to all apps